# After upgrade Magento 2 : JS-translation.json file not Generating on Production Mode

Tags: admin, frontend, magento2.2.3

When  run `setup:static-content:deploy` command then *`js-translation.json`* not generating.

So it is creating an issue in admin to load order, customer and product grid.
File Path is

> pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json

And same file not generating on the frontend.

> /pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US

Comment: This file creating in developer mode.
Anyone know what is the  problem?

Comment: If you have found how to solve this problem, please reply https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231752/magento-2-js-translation-json-404-not-found-on-production-mode

Comment: Ok, Please Reply me also if you found any solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

*Use this command :*
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US -f`
I had problem in admin panel and  I ran
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/backend en_US -f`
This command created
`js-translation.json`
in
`pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json`

Comment: I will check and reply you soon.

Comment: which Magento version you are using?

Comment: @Jugal Kishor 2.2.3

Comment: I checked Your command working. Thanks very much

Comment: Then choose it please as the best)