# Magento 2: js-translation.json 404 (Not Found) on production mode

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, production-mode, translate

After switching to the production mode, an error appeared in the console :

```
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json 404 (Not Found)
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json HTTP status: 404
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (text.min.js:8)
```

I was looking for a solution, I found such solutions:

```
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

**and run**

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

*or*

```
 php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

**And I'm trying this :**

> In vendor/magento/module-translation/Model/Json/PreProcessor.php

```
 $area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
 $area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

needs to be:

```
$area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_DESIGN);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

**But** this did not help me, Magento still does not find the file :

```
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used this command :

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US -f
```

This command created `js-translation.json`.

**This solved my problem.**

Comment: Not working for me in magento 2.3.6 version..

Comment: Very helpful! This solved my problem after adding multi-language store views. I'm on Magento 2.4.5-p3.

Comment: @seanbreeden, I'm glad I could help you)

Answer (score 1):

Solution not working for me either on Magento 2.4.
The files not being generated and publishing static content throws an error

```
Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s.
```

Very informative. When modifing code to display variables that should be substitued the problem is

```
Warning: MessageFormatter::formatMessage(): pattern syntax error (parse error at offset 3, after "${ ", before or at "$.visible } out") in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/Renderer/MessageFormatter.php on line 43
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "${ $.visible } out of ${ $.total } visible"
}
```

and in the file is this

```
templates: {
  headerMsg: $t('${ $.visible } out of ${ $.total } visible')
}
```

It's in magento/magento-ui package.

---

magento/module-ui is 101.2.5

magento/module-translation is 100.4.5

---

What helps is to disable waning errors in PHP, change log level to error and above. But magento sets it's own level reporting E_ALL and in ErrorHandler trows an exception. On production I quite don't see reason for warnings to be this hard. The dirty fix is to modify `app/bootstrap.php` and set the

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING);
```

Answer (score 0):

i was helped

```
bin/magento app:config:import
bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```