# js-translation.json fails to generated

Tags: magento-2.1, localisation, json, static-content-deploy, js-translation

Magento 2.1

We have a site setup with both English and French languages. We were noticing some french translations weren't showing on checkout page. Upon further inspection js-translation.json was missing.

Ran,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -v
```

We get back the following error,

```
#0 /home/magento/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /home/magento/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Model/Deployer.php(445): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Model/Deployer.php(302): Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer->deployFile('js-translation....', 'frontend', 'Magento/luma', 'fr_FR', NULL)
#4 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(447): Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer->deploy(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory), Array, Array)
#5 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(468): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer), Array, Array)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\{closure}(Object(Magento\Deploy\Model\Process))
#7 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Model/Process.php(53): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Deploy\Model\Process))
#8 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Model/ProcessManager.php(41): Magento\Deploy\Model\Process->run()
#9 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(486): Magento\Deploy\Model\ProcessManager->fork(Object(Closure))
#10 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(371): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->runProcessesInParallel(Object(Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer), Array, Array)
#11 /home/magento/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(257): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /home/magento/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /home/magento/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(195): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /home/magento/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Console/Cli.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /home/magento/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(126): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /home/magento/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#17 {main}

Successful: 2729 files; errors: 1
```

Looking for information on what this error is exactly and any possible fixes.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223053/after-upgrade-magento-2-js-translation-json-file-not-generating-on-production

Comment: My answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use this command :**

Please set `Vendor= Your vendor name and Theme= Your theme name` for frontend

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme fr_FR
```

I had problem in admin panel and I ran

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/backend en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/backend fr_FR
```

This command created

```
js-translation.json

pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json
pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/fr_FR/js-translation.json
```